# Using PHP DOM to create XML files from MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql, xml, dom

I have created a MySQL table and would like to save the contents of the table in an XML file for use by other applications. I can access the data fine and echo the data on a broswer window, but on saving using the DomDocument::save('thexmlfile.xml'), I cannot see any new files created in the directory location of the running PHP file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to create the dom xml from the mysql data and then save it in an xml file.An example:

```
$sql = 'select * from messages';
$run = mysql_query($sql, $link);

if( $run && mysql_num_rows( $run ) ) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument( '1.0' );
    $doc->formatOutput = true;
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = true;

    $root = $doc->createElement( 'data' );
    $doc->appendChild( $root );

    while( ( $fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc( $run ) )!== false ) {
        $node = $doc->createElement( 'node' );
        $root->appendChild( $node );

        foreach( $fetch as $key => $value ) {
            createNodes( $key, $value, $doc, $node );
        }
    }
    $doc->save("thexmlfile.xml");
}

function createNodes( $key, $value, $doc, $node ) {
    $key = $doc->createElement( $key );
    $node->appendChild( $key );
    $key->appendChild( $doc->createTextNode( $value ) );
}
```

Now, you should see the xml file.

Hope, it helps.

Comment: Thank you @Pushpesh. problem is,I am now getting an error "XML Parsing Error: syntax error
Location: protocal://localhost/practice/displayQueue.php
Line Number 1, Column 1:Data not found." This's also shown when I comment the line $doc->save("thexmlfile.xml") and add echo doc->saveXML();

^

Comment: ok, do you have the mysql table structure i gave in my example...or if you have a separate structure, post it here...i will make suitable changes...

Comment: I created table using CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `senderNumber` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `smsMessage` varchar(1600) default NULL,
  `sentTime` timestamp NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `receivedTime` datetime default NULL,
  `operator` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `messageType` varchar(50) default 'SMS:TEXT',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM; Now on displaying i just want to display 3 fields senderNumber, smsMessage and timeReceived.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, your question is about `DOM`, the accepted answer is about `DOM`, but you don't seem to need the capabilities of this, then libxml's brother `SimpleXML` seems much more straight forward... I assume your problem is long over, but just for completeness sake:

```
$sql = 'select * from messages';
$run = mysql_query($sql, $link);

if( $run && mysql_num_rows( $run ) ) {
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<data/>');
    while($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($run)) {
        $node = $root->addChild('node');
        foreach( $fetch as $key => $value ) {
            $node->addChild($key,$value);
        }
    }
    $xml->asXML("thexmlfile.xml");
}
```