# Why is ALL my XML being escaped?

Tags: c#, php, xml, web-services, nusoap

Long time listener, first time caller.

Here is what I got going on...

Created a PHP webservice, no problem with sending simple data types like string, int...
No problem returning string or int.

Now I want to return data in XML.

So I created a DomDocument and filled in all the data...

Then I return it out of the service.

On my client side when I go to load the object as an XML document I get an error about my root not being properly formated.

I look at my debug and all the "special" characters have been escaped.

I did a hack and replaced "<" with > and so on.

Then I can load the result.

This does not seem right, I should be able to return XML with it properly formatted.

So I am guessing it is in how I defined the xml object???

Can someone post a sample of PHP defining the return of an xml object?

I have looked for days and I cannot find a simple example of selecting data from MySql turning it to XML and then returning the XML to a client.

Comment: `Then I return it out of the service`, what _exactly_ are you doing at this stage?

Answer (score 1):

```
I did a hack and replaced "<" with > and so on.
```

There's no hack about **replacing .XML harmful characters**, its the rule.
Read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) about such characters.
Instead, you can use this code:

```
function replace_characters_for_xml(&$str)
{
   $str = str_replace("&","&amp;",$str);
   $str = str_replace(">","&gt;",$str);
   $str = str_replace("<","&lt;",$str);
   $str = str_replace("'","&apos;",$str);
   $str = str_replace('"',"&quot;",$str);
}
...
replace_characters_for_xml($string);
```

Comment: That is what I did on my client side. seems odd though.

Answer (score 0):

> So I created a DomDocument and filled in all the data...

I suspect that whatever you did here was done wrong.

Comment: Using the DomDocument is fairly hands off in terms of the creating the  root. I getting this everywhere in the xml result.  I readsomething about this happening when returning xml inside of xml. Which why I am thinking it deals with how I am returing the xml object in the service.

Answer (score 0):

I found a different code example for storing MySql data into XML.
This did the trick as to what I was looking for as a result.

[Using PHP DOM to create XML files from MySQL data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10009029/using-php-dom-to-create-xml-files-from-mysql-data)